# Intent does not work in case of if else

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Here is my sample code:

```
String checkin = imageUpload.getStatus();
if (checkin.equals("1")) {
    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, name+" "+ "Checked In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(FullImageActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    //openCamera.setText("CheckOut");
} else if (checkin.equals("0")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name + " " + "Checked Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The first one if is working fine but the second was is not. No activity change in the second stage. Please give me idea here.

Comment: try with checkin.equalsIgnoreCase("0")

Comment: did you get a Toast in the second case?

Comment: equalsIgnorCase doesn´t matter in case of string numbers

Comment: why do you use `getApplicationContext()` in the second case?

Comment: without getApplicationContext() it works the same

Comment: They are under same package so no problem.

Comment: If you are getting toast in second case then It is impossible that the `Intent` is not working.

Comment: have you thought about that  `checkin` has never been `0` ? Make a Log to check, maybe the wrong implementation of code is somewhere before....

Comment: @JasonBourne Which value are you getting in checkin ?

Comment: don't use getApplicationContext() as it may be null.. Use FullImageActivity.this for getting current instance. Hope it will help :)

Comment: @Opiatefuchs - OP has seen a Toast in the second case, so this is... really mysterious.

Comment: oh, yep...your wright I see the comment...

Comment: @JasonBourne - are there any Intent extras which you send with the Intent in startActivity(..., MainActivity.class)? Surely you don't want to react the target acitivity in the same way no matter what the checkin value is.

Comment: possible: change the way you get the intent to `FullImageActivity.this` and **important** UNINSTALL,, CLEAN PROJECT,  INSTALL NEW

Comment: I am using this Code : 

String checkin = imageUpload.getStatus();
                    if (checkin.equals("1")) {
                        Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, name+" "+ "Checked In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, name + " " + "Checked Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    startActivity(i);

Getting right result while debugging but in app running did not.

Comment: Guys this looks like paranormal scene to me

Comment: have you made the clean? I mean with deinstall the app and install again after clean?

Comment: I am aksing because on some devices Android Studio make the install and shows also a correct log in the "run" tab but it doesn´t install it correctly, so the old version stays on the device....

Comment: Thanks guyz. Full clean and build works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answers here ,it seems that this issue is by multiple problems. As some here pointed out to take `FullImageActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`, my assumption was that it was not `rebuild` correctly. So for everybody who has the same problem: On some devices(eg. Huawei Ascend mate 7) , `Android Studio` doesn´t install the new version after an update correctly althought it shows this in the `Run` tab.

**The best way to update after some code changes is to uninstall from device, clean project and reinstall your app.**

So, this answer is not a code example (this part about the context is allready said) but important and fixed the problem of the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

SO try using it in Switch case :

```
   int checkin = Integer.parseInt(imageUpload.getStatus());
                switch(checkin) 
                 {
                 case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, name+" "+ "Checked In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(FullImageActivity.this, Activiy_1.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //openCamera.setText("CheckOut");
                    break;
                case 0:    
                    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, name + " " + "Checked Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activiy_0.class);
                    startActivity(intent);''
                    break;
                default:
                    //default methods

                }
```

Hope this works for you....

**EDITED ::**

If string works then

```
 String checkin = imageUpload.getStatus();
                switch(checkin) 
                 {
                 case "1":
                    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, name+" "+ "Checked In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //openCamera.setText("CheckOut");
                    break;
                case "0":    
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name + " " + "Checked Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);''
                    break;
                default:
                    //default methods

                }
```

Comment: i have parse the string to a integer    int checkin = Integer.parseInt(imageUpload.getStatus());

Comment: Starting with Java 7 which Android supports, you can compare strings directly in your switch cases. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html (the example is about three pages down on that page, sorry I don't have a direct link)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming imageUpload is an asynch task instance, you forgot to test for the PENDING [Status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html).

So the final result would look something like this:

```
String message = "";
String checkin = imageUpload.getStatus();
switch(checkin) {
      case Status.FINISHED:
             message = "Checked In";
             break;
       case Status.RUNNING:    
             message = "Checked Out";
             break;
       case Status.PENDING:    
             message = "Trying";
             break;
        default:
             message = "Arghhhh";  
 }

 Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, name + " " + message,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Intent i = new Intent(FullImageActivity.this, Activiy_1.class);
 startActivity(i);

// You'll have to test this yourself. I didn't test it.
```

*Ideally, it's better to use static final variables for the status strings, since those never change and this way you don't have to remember what their values mean.*

*Also if you really start the same Activity whatever happens, then that's duplicate code, and you can do that part outside of the switch statement.*

*The same goes for showing the Toast. It seems to me like only the content of the Toast changes, so only that content needs to be in the switch.*

Answer (score 0):

This lines of Code worked for me. 
 We dont need to create two intents for if else. Just create one and call the startactivity after if else. 
That is it.

```
ImageUpload imageUpload = response.body();
    Intent i = new Intent(FullImageActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    String checkin = imageUpload.getStatus();
    if (checkin.equals("1")) {
    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, name+" "+ "Checked In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } else {
    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, name + " " + "Checked Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }

  startActivity(i);
```

Comment: This code worked for you as often as you tested (after following @Opiatefuchs' advice), **but** Stefan Branczyk is right about testing for all possible return codes to be on the safe side. Anyway, for me, the lesson to be learned here is not about code: your problem seemed to be caused by device/ emulator behaviour when installing a new version of your app (--> "Full clean and build works here"). I really think this should be part of the answer.